# Why are opacity wrapping my main content?

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color, opacity

I want to have a background image in my main section.
Then there will be an empty div below it.
It will have an opacity of 0.8.
Below that there will be a div that will contain my content and that content will have an opacity of 1. Or that I gave 0.8 opacity above so that it doesn't get into the bottom content box.
How to do it?

I want to make it like this:

[image]

```css
.opening-job-parent{
    background-image: url("./images/header-banner-image-one.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 30vh;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.opening-job-parent .empty-div{
    background-color: #7f73eb;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.opening-job-container{
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<section class="opening-job-parent">
    <div class="empty-div">

    </div>
    <div class="opening-job-container">
        <div class="opening-job-details">
            <div class="opening-job-text">
                <h1>Over 10k opening jobs</h1>
                <p>If you are looking for free HTML templates, <br> you may visit Tooplate website. <br> If you need
                    a
                    collection of free templates, <br> you can visit Too CSS website.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="opening-job-account-link">
                <a href="#">Create an account</a>
                <a href="#">Post a job</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: "opacity wrapping my main content?" - what are we talking about?

Comment: empty div opacity wrapping my text. but I want empty div opacity are not wrapping my content. how to do boss ? I added an image on my post see that iimage please.

Comment: Just give .opening-job-container position relative and it should be fine. Or add z-index 1 as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved your problem.

```css
.one {
    position: relative;
}

.one img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.one .empty-div {
    background-color: #7f73eb;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 520px;
    max-height: 520px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.8;
    top: 30%;
    right: 20%;
}

.one .opening-job-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 420px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: .3 ease;
    gap: 35px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="one p-0">
    <img class="img-fluid" src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/1059/600/495.jpg?hmac=tULMNx8RZcb-7PPKKp-o_-hNedg3OdCJNDG2NUGHXiU" alt="new1">
    <div class="empty-div"></div>
    <div class="opening-job-container">
        <div class="opening-job-details">
            <div class="opening-job-text">
                <h1>Over 10k opening jobs</h1>
                <p>If you are looking for free HTML templates, <br> you may visit Tooplate website. <br> If you need
                    a
                    collection of free templates, <br> you can visit Too CSS website.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="opening-job-account-link">
                <a href="#">Create an account</a>
                <a href="#">Post a job</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't link to a potentially transient source. Add the output to the answer if it's essential. Also, please add an explanation for future readers, because Stack Overflow is a knowledge base, not just a Q&A site.

Comment: There I have it as you wish in css `.opening-job-container` class add for background set

Comment: and another one `empty-div` add in class width to send right block